# How does this deduction come about? -(trig,convergence,complex analysis)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, convergence-divergence

I'll start it off, and highlight what I don't understand:

Lets assume that $z_0= \rho_0(\cos \varphi_0+i \sin \varphi_0)\neq0, where  -\pi<\varphi_0<\pi,$ or $z_0$ isn't a negative real number.

Let's look at the function $$l(\varphi)=\cos \varphi+i \sin \varphi. \\ \text{ then } |l(\varphi_n)-l(\varphi)|=2|\sin\frac{\varphi-\varphi_n}{2}|$$ Up to here, all is clear but then(this is the unclear part):

So for $|\varphi_n-\varphi|< \pi$

$$\frac{|\varphi_n-\varphi|}{\pi}\leq |l(\varphi_n)-l(\varphi)|\leq|\varphi_n-\varphi|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an application of the inequality

$$\frac{2}{\pi}x \leqslant \sin x \leqslant x$$

that holds for $x \in \bigl[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr]$. For $\lvert \varphi - \varphi_n\rvert < \pi$, we have $0 \leqslant \frac{\lvert \varphi - \varphi_n\rvert}{2} < \frac{\pi}{2}$, so we can apply the above inequality to $x = \frac{\lvert \varphi - \varphi_n\rvert}{2}$.